# strcat not working when trying to add a string and a char?

Tags: c

One of the first times I'm using C. I can't append the string every time I encounter a capital letter. I understand that this is very simple in most languages but I am trying to learn it in C.

```
string s = get_string();
string s1 = "";

for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
{
    if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')
    {
        strcat (s1,s[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If `string` is a typedef for a pointer to `char`, then `s1` points to a string literal; it is undefined behavior to modify a string literal, for example, by concatenating another string to it.

Comment: Whichever book you're reading obviously isn't working for you; as people who read [K&R2E](https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-Brian-W-Kernighan/dp/0131103628), for example, don't tend to have this kind of basic problem with language fundamentals, I can recommend that book.

Comment: The CS50 course (questions often tagged [tag:cs50] — and there's also the [CS50](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange web site) use `typedef char *string;` (and the `get_string()` function).  The OP is probably working on code related to that.

Comment: `if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')`-- there is no guarantee that this will work, since there are few restrictions on the character encoding used by an implementation. Better, and portable, to use `isupper()` from `ctype.h`.

Comment: @DavidBowling Please name an implementation in which that doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidBowling that logic is just for the time being. Once I get the concatenation working I'm gonna change that logic and use '\0' to find the first letters.

Comment: @ErikW-- for example, it would not work for some legacy IBM systems that used [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC). The point is, the Standard does not specify the encoding, and such assumptions are not portable. Only a comment. But this is one reason to prefer library functions when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcat` is defined like this: `char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);` which means that it can only concatenate two strings with eachother. What you can do (in modern C) is this:

```
strcat(s1, (char[]){s[i], '\0'});
```

You have another problem though; `s1` is a string literal. It is undefined behavior trying to concatenate it with another string. You will either have to make an array or allocate it on the heap to use it correctly.

```
char s1[128];
```

or

```
char* s1 = malloc(128);
```

Notice that those implementations cannot hold strings larger than 127 characters, and you have to add NUL termination yourself.

Comment: It works. Thank you @ErikW. I have two questions tho. 1) What is the * after char and 2) Can you add to your answer, how you got `(char[]){s[i], '\0'})`

Comment: @TodLazarov 1) The `*` after `char` means that it is a pointer to `char`. I believe it is the same as the `string` in your code. `string` won't work elsewhere though, because it is not standard. 2) `(char[]){s[i], '\0'}` is a compound literal, basically an array

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: Can I ask you another question? When iterating through a string, does C cache the whole string? What I mean is, if Im at the i'th iteration, can I access `i+1`?

Comment: @TodLazarov yes

Comment: "if Im at the `i`'th iteration, can I access `i+1`?"-- If `i+1` is within the array bounds, then yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: Thanks guys. You were very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

-shudders- I now have two reasons to boycott CS50.

- It appears to be teaching you to use an unsuitable storage duration.
- It's teaching you to use an unsuitable type alias.

[C11/7.1.1p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1p1) tells us that a variable declared with this `typedef` can meaningfully store a *pointer to a string* (a pointer to a string is *"a pointer to its initial (lowest addressed) character"*) **if** it points at an object storing a *sequence of values* fitting a very specific pattern (a string is *"a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character"*).

You need to pass a *pointer to a modifiable string* as the first argument of `strcat`. As it currently stands, you're passing a *pointer to a string literal* as the first argument, and as others have said this causes undefined behaviour.

Here's a modifiable string:

```
char str[128] = "hello";
```

Actually, there are 127 modifiable strings there, and they have *pointers to strings* like this:

- `str + 0` or `&str[0]` points at the first
- `str + 1` or `&str[1]` points at the second
- *and so on up until*
- `str + 126` or `&str[126]` points at the 127th
- `str + 127` or `&str[127]` points at a 128th, but you can't change this (empty) string without accessing `str` out of bounds and causing undefined behaviour.

You can call `fgets(str, 128, stdin)` to obtain a string, which likely contains a newline (`'\n'`) character (if it doesn't, then the line is incomplete)... Strip the newline with `str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';` and then you can use `strcat(str, (char[]){s[i], '\0'});`... *providing* you don't overflow the array.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. Also there is no need to be negative about a class which stirs up a lot of passion for programming to a ton of people.

Comment: @TodLazarov I disagree with your premise, and this renders your assertion invalid; when a class involves misinforming people, it *should* be constructively criticised. This answer forms some constructive criticism. To be clear, there's nothing *abusive* here. I'm sure the suggestion *not to `typedef char *string;`* has been put to the professor/s of that class many times, as I've witnessed highly reputable people of the C programming group of Freenode, for example, submit such feedback. Would you like to learn from a professor who refuses to correct misinformation, or a humble professor?

Comment: To be clear, your premise is that I'm being *negative* by providing constructive criticism. When the teacher explains that fuel, oxygen and heat are necessary ingredients for fire, the teacher is *misinforming* students; electrical and thermite fires, for example, don't need oxygen, and this could lead to confusion later on. **Your resource is causing confusion** as `typedef char *string;` is a common mistake. Like it or lump it. It's the truth, and it should be addressed.

Comment: You are forgetting a very important point in all of this though. What the teacher teaches and what the student learns are not always the same thing. And that is especially true with these online courses, which just about anyone with a computer can take. And the second thing you are forgetting is that in my experience with these courses, they dont always give you everything you need, you have to go out and find a lot of it on your own, which can also lead to misunderstanding and errors.

Comment: @TodLazarov That is very different to *teaching misunderstandings and errors*; when what the teacher teaches and what the student learns *are* the same thing, yet the teacher is *teaching misunderstandings and errors*, this equates to a poor lesson. A poor lesson in most subjects is relatively harmless, but in C it can be devastating. It's important to ensure the teachers are teaching accurately to avoid. It took me about seven minutes to find a second major misunderstanding. Perhaps I'll compile a list for you...

Comment: In week1 "...`%lu\n", sizeof`..."; **a/** according to [6.5.3.4p5](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p5), the type of a `sizeof` expression "is size_t..." **b/** according to [7.21.6.1p7](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p7), the `l` in this format string "Specifies that a following ...u... conversion specifier applies to a ...unsigned long int argument;"...

Comment: ... **c/** according to [p9](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9), "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined." **d/** a `size_t` (point a) is not an `unsigned long int` (point b), and so **the behaviour is undefined** (point c). This may cause confusion among students when they enter into employment as they might later find *all* of their code *crashes* (or is vulnerable) for certain implementations. Just how much do you want hackers in your nuclear facilities?

Comment: *"We know that ints have 4 bytes set aside for them, which is 32 bits, so 2^32 possible values..."* It seems as though the teacher is more interested in teaching *common implementations* of C, as the C standard doesn't guarantee `INT_MIN` any less than -32767 or `INT_MAX` any greater than 32767, let alone `CHAR_BIT` exactly equal to 8, number of padding bits equal to 0 or a twos complement representation. This is different to teaching C, as C is a portable language and this is all non-portable assumption.

Comment: *"We can change n to long long and print it out with %lld, but at the last step we still see it "wrap around" to a negative number."* Integer overflow on a signed integer of any kind is *always* undefined behaviour (see above about UB); the result may instead be a trap representation (padding bits; what are those? negative zero; what's that?) or `SIGFPE` being thrown, which would... *hopefully* cause a crash.

Comment: This brings me to the end of week 1... Shall I continue, @TodLazarov?

Comment: In week2, *"... since characters have an integer value due to ASCII..."*; there's no such requirement that ASCII be used in C. In fact, the next most common alternative, EBCDIC, does not have the same patterns as this weeks lesson demonstrate in *"`for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)`"* and in *"... a lowercase letter has a value exactly 32 higher than the same letter in uppercase."* [See for yourself](https://www.clivemaxfield.com/diycalculator/imgs/codes-07.gif); the code used in week 2 would likely loop through *not just the uppercase characters* but *also many lowercase and non-alpha*!

Comment: `if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z')
            {
                printf("%c", s[i] - ('a' - 'A'));`... yikes! Imagine the bugs on EBCDIC systems! It's a shame they introduced this *prior* to the standard `islower` and `toupper` functions!

Comment: @TodLazarov Here's my contribution for today: issues [#66: Optimistic bounds check causes potential memory leaks and off-by-one or null pointer dereference](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/issues/66), [#67: Complex, pervasive memory leaks throughout user input functions](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/issues/67), [#68: Undefined behaviour caused by invalid values passed to character type (`<ctype.h>`) functions](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/issues/68). See also [#59](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/issues/59) (not mine). Would you like to learn to make these kinds of mistakes? Your choice!